# If $d_1(x,y)$ and $d_2(x,y)$ are metrics, prove that $d'(x,y)= \sqrt{d_1^2(x,y)+d_2^2(x,y)}$ is a metric.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

$$d'(x,y)= \sqrt{d_1^2(x,y)+d_2^2(x,y)}$$

The first three properties are trivially proven. The triangle inequality, not so much. I tried using the triangle inequalities that apply to $d_1$ and $d_2$, but nothing tangible came out of that. I feel the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality might be applicable to find the answer, but am not sure as to how...

Comment: Apply triangle inequality for $d_1$ and $d_2$ and than for the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Could you go into more detail concerning the  Euclidean norm?

Comment: The Euclidean norm $\| u \|_2 = \sqrt{ u_1^2 + u_2^2 }$ satisfies the triangle inequality in the form: $\| u + v \|_2 \le \|u\|_2 + \|v\|_2$.

Comment: Yes, I understand this but applying it I find difficult (very), intuitively this is very promising path towards the answer.

Comment: I cannot formally prove it. :)

Comment: just tell us where you stop and can't continue.

Comment: When I apply the triangle inequality for $d_1$ and $d_2$ as you say I get a large term under the root, after which I cannot see how to apply the euclidean norm..

Comment: Notice that $0 \le x \le y + z$ implies $x^2 \le (y + z)^2$.

Comment: I honestly don't know\see how that comes into play after the first step that I make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x, y, z$ be given. Then, we have
$$ \begin{align}
d(x, z) &= \sqrt{ d_1^2(x,z) + d_2^2(x,z) } \\
& \le \sqrt{ (d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z))^2 + (d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z))^2 } \\
& \le \sqrt{ (d_1(x,y))^2 + (d_2(x,y))^2 } + \sqrt{ (d_1(y,z))^2 + (d_2(y,z))^2 } \\
&= d(x,y) + d(y,z).
\end{align}$$

Comment: I just cannot comprehend $\sqrt{ (d_1(x,y)+d_1(y,z))^2 + (d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z))^2 } \\
\leq \sqrt{ (d_1(x,y))^2 + (d_2(x,y))^2 } + \sqrt{ (d_1(y,z))^2 + (d_2(y,z))^2 }$ (second to third line transition)

Comment: @JimLowe that's the triangle inequality for the Euclidean norm

Comment: This is very impressive, and I thank you very much for enlightening this for me. :)

Comment: I'm stuck on that same step. Are there lots of computations in between? I must be missing something obvious, because I can't see a straightforward application of $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \leq \sqrt{a^2+c^2}+ \sqrt{b^2+c^2}$. If it is straightforward, what are your $a,b,$ and $c$?

Comment: @JimLowe you might also have a look to the Minkowski inequality - just in case you still find it a bit confusing, there you'll see that this is just an application of the inequality for sums

Comment: @ColdNumber I haven't claimed what you wrote. In fact, I am not sure whether it is right.

Comment: That's what I thought the triangle inequality for the Euclidean metric was: $d(a,b)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$

Comment: @ColdNumber nope. sorry. I have stated the triangle inequality in the comments to the question.

Comment: Right, that's what you wrote to explain that step, and what I wrote was $d(a,b)\leq d(a,c)+d(b,c)$. Isn't that the triangle inequality?

Comment: @ColdNumber nope. The metric defined by the Euclidean norm looks different.

Comment: Well, what does it look like in general? What I wrote in my last comment is the triangle inequality for a general metric, and my first comment just replaced it with the definition of the Euclidean metric.

Comment: @ColdNumber Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$ is $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|_2 = \sqrt{|x_1-y_1| + |x_2-y_2|}$.

Comment: @ColdNumber Just look at it this way: $\| u \|_2 = \sqrt{ u_1^2 + u_2^2 }$

Comment: @ColdNumber $ \| u + v \|_2 \le \|u\|_2 + \|v\|_2$

Comment: @ColdNumber and from the second line just make out what $u$ and $v$ are

Comment: @user251257: really, no squares under the square root? .

Comment: @JimLowe yes, that's the definition I have, and I'm trying to make out what they are but can't

Comment: @ColdNumber with squares. my bad. I am typing on a smartphone. isn't that easy :)

Comment: @ColdNumber $u=(d_1(x,y), d_2(x,y)) $ and $v=(d_1(y,z), d_2(y,z))$  and also $d_1(x,y)..d_2(z,y)$ are real numbers so the Euclidean triangle inequality is valid....

Comment: It almost checks out with those, but the signs on the left-hand side, inside the squares, are pluses, not minuses. I.e.,  you have $(d_i(x,y)+d_i(y,z))^2$, not $(d_i(x,y)-d_i(y,z))^2$, like you would with coordinates.

Comment: @ColdNumber if you use the triangle inequality as .@JimLowe suggested, there is no minus.

Comment: Oh wow okay I see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The square of a metric is a metric, the sum of two metrics is a metric, and the square root of a metric is a metric. It then immediately follows that $d'$ is a metric. The proof for each of these is a lot simpler, than directly showing $d'$ is a metric.

Comment: Square of the Euclidean metric in one dimension $d(x_1, x_2) = |x_1 - x_2|^2$ does not satisfy the triangle inequality – for instance if $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 2$ we obtain $(1-0)^2 + (2 - 1)^2 \leq (2 - 0)^2$.